# Regex search of 2 or 3 words which start with a specific letter

Tags: excel, regex, cpu-word, acronym

I'm working in multiple large excel and word files and I need to search for phrases. Let's say I have the acronym "PC" and I need to search for a word that starts with "P" followed by another word which starts with "D" e.g. "Phase change"; or if I have MEL,I need to find "Monitoring and Evaluation and Learning (MEL)"
Can anyone help me?

I don't know regex. So I don't know where to start with.

Comment: Apparently "and" does not count as a word. If this is so, then please provide a complete list of words that are not words.

Comment: *"P" followed by another word which starts with "D" e.g. "Phase change"*... where is the `D`? Hmm, for your 2nd example `MEL` something to get started could be: [`\bM[a-z ]+E[a-z ]+L[a-z]+`](https://regex101.com/r/5nAdDp/1) (explanation on the right side)

Comment: It could be an "and", "or" or a comma. e.g. "Monitoring, Evaluating and Learning". I was given the wrong phrase. Sorry for the mistakes!